How to change elastic Eck operator setting to create node sets as Kind: Deployment instead of StatefulSet?
In our environment when we tried scaling up the node, so Eck operator creates new node as Stateful Set which is default behavior but, we want it as a Deployment.
Could anyone help me where to change in the template file or is it supported by Eck operator.

It is not possible. I assume you are trying to create Elasticsearch NodeSet. If so it is stateful by nature, Elasticsearch is sateful application and it must be done with Statefulset.
